# Laravel 4 Email not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, swiftmailer

I've been looking for the answer for two days and still nothing. I've followed several tutorials where nothing more than just a few config settings are required, but my Laravel 4 app still doesn't want to send an e-mail. It always throws the same Exception and nobody seems to have the answer. It seems that I've tried everything but the working one.

```
Route::get('/sendemail', function() {
    $data['user'] = 'Test User';
    Mail::send('email.test', $data, function($m) {
          $m->to('myemail@example.com')->subject('Email test');
    });
});
```

But when I'm in the specified route, it always throws the same error:

> Argument 1 passed to Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport::__construct()
>   must implement interface Swift_Transport_IoBuffer, none given

The config is ok and even changing the driver from 'smtp' to 'mail' in `config/mail.php` throws also Exception.

> Argument 1 passed to Swift_Transport_MailTransport::__construct() must be an instance of Swift_Transport_MailInvoker, none given

I'm stuck in here and I don't know that to do. My composer is up to date and PHP version is 5.4.4.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably found an answer by now.
But I think you need a second argument for the **to**.

Try:

```
$data = array('user' => $user);
Mail::send('email.test', $data, function($message) use ($user)
{
  $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Email Test');
});
```